# Where would Talne, Vine, Germany or Talue, Germany be today?

Tags: germany, poland, historical-gazetteer, prussia

I am attempting to find my stepsisters 2nd Great Grandfathers birth town.  He immigrated to the US in 1885, but documents show he was born in Talne, Vine, Germany in 1865.  His last name is Ulatowski.  There are no surviving documents that I have found of him mentioning who his parents are or where exactly he came from.  And of course, his children and grandchilden who may have talked about it are either no longer here, or do not remember.

The family is very vested in their Polish roots.  And I know this is a very hard line to try to follow.

Not that these are definitive, but the US Census's list him as Prussian, German, and Polish.

Talne, Vine, Germany is only listed on one document.  And the one document I can find his father named is listed as coming from Talue, Germany.  I know there is a Talne, Ukraine, but I'm not sure that is correct but I really don't know.

Comment: Can you post an image from a scanned document?

Comment: Chmielewo, now Pisz County, Poland [formerly in East Prussia] seems to have had the alternative name Talau. May be a possibility, depending on the handwriting and the document date.